# How to plot month values on the year scale?

Tags: r

I have the following data: year and values for 12 months.
How to plot the values with respect to time (denoted by years) with the spacing that there will be 12 values between the two years? Thank you

```
 1847   0.031   0.099  -1.585   1.170   1.763  -0.260   0.746   1.129  -0.324   0.445   2.459   1.760  
 1848  -0.792   1.770   0.757  -1.023   0.691  -1.780   1.867   2.641  -2.546  -2.436  -0.842   2.548  
 1849   2.419   2.767  -0.562  -0.990  -0.517  -3.210   1.203   0.701  -2.234  -0.078   0.802  -1.238  
 1850  -0.163   4.134  -2.216   0.965  -1.157   0.403   0.305   0.148  -2.077  -2.701   2.390   2.358  
 1851   3.293   1.028   1.504  -1.658  -1.534  -1.621  -5.395   4.679   1.852   0.777  -1.769   1.742  
 1852   1.464   0.411  -2.502  -1.597   0.245   0.093  -1.134   2.943  -2.021  -1.646  -0.930   1.029
```

Something like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, if you wanted to put all values in a single line:

```
dat <- import("https://quantoid.net/files/test.txt")
names(dat) <- c("year", paste0("month_", 1:12))
dat <- dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(-year, names_pattern="month_(\\d+)", names_to="month", values_to="val") %>% 
  mutate(month = as.numeric(month), 
         yrmo = year + (month - 1)/12)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=yrmo, y=val)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1847:1852)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution using the `zoo` package for neat plotted dates and the `highcharter` package to generate the chart, as well as the `tidyverse` to sort data.

```
library(zoo)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
```

I emulated your dataset as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(rep(1847,12),rep(1848,12),rep(1849,12),rep(1850,12),rep(1851,12),rep(1852,12)),
           month = c(rep(seq(01,12, by = 01),6)),
           values = c(runif(72, min = -2, max = 2)       
)) %>%
  unite("date",c(year,month),sep = "-") %>%
  mutate(date = as.yearmon(date)
) %>%
  mutate(color = ifelse(values >= 0, "above", "below"))
```

Which yields something like this:

```
head(df)
      date     values color
1 Jan 1847  0.7233567 above
2 Feb 1847  0.4621962 above
3 Mar 1847 -0.2388412 below
4 Apr 1847 -0.3818243 below
5 May 1847 -1.5017872 below
6 Jun 1847 -1.8706521 below
```

I created a variable that indicates whether the value is above or below 0. I then plot using highcharter's column plot function:

```
colors <- c("slateblue","firebrick")
df %>%
hchart("column", hcaes(x = date, y = values, group = color)) %>%
  hc_title(text = "My Chart Title",
           align =  "center",
           style = list(
             fontSize = '2em',
             color = "#000000"
           ))  %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_colors(colors)
```

Which yields:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. Is it possible to not write all years? year = c(rep(1847,12),rep(1848,12),rep(1849,12),rep(1850,12),rep(1851,12),rep(1852,12)) I have much more years in the real data.

Comment: What format is your data in? Because what will take you the most time is writing down the values, I just generated some random ones in my code as an example. Is it a csv, excel file?

Answer (score 1):

A `ggplot()` version with `facet_wrap()`

Sample data:

```
  df<-read.table(header=T,text=
    "Year   January February March April    May     June    July    August  October September November December
     1847   0.031   0.099  -1.585   1.170   1.763  -0.260   0.746   1.129  -0.324   0.445   2.459   1.760  
     1848  -0.792   1.770   0.757  -1.023   0.691  -1.780   1.867   2.641  -2.546  -2.436  -0.842   2.548  
     1849   2.419   2.767  -0.562  -0.990  -0.517  -3.210   1.203   0.701  -2.234  -0.078   0.802  -1.238  
     1850  -0.163   4.134  -2.216   0.965  -1.157   0.403   0.305   0.148  -2.077  -2.701   2.390   2.358  
     1851   3.293   1.028   1.504  -1.658  -1.534  -1.621  -5.395   4.679   1.852   0.777  -1.769   1.742  
     1852   1.464   0.411  -2.502  -1.597   0.245   0.093  -1.134   2.943  -2.021  -1.646  -0.930   1.029")
```

Sample code:

```
 library(lubridate)
 library(ggplot)

df_melt<-melt(df, id.var="Year")
df_melt$Year<- as.factor(df_melt$Year)


ggplot(df_melt, aes(x=value, y=variable, group=Year)) +  
geom_col(aes(fill=value))+theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~as.factor(Year))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="lightyellow", high="red") + 
  labs(x="", y="", title="", fill="r") + 
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,  face="bold", size=20, color="black")) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( hjust = 1,  face="bold", size=14, color="black") )+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text( hjust = 1,  face="bold", size=14, color="black") )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 14,face="bold"),
        legend.position="right",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 16, colour = "black",family="Times", face="bold"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -year
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y=value, color=factor(name), group=name)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

colnames(df) <- c("year", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -year
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y=value, color=factor(year), group=year)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: You probably want to make the years a factor with the levels ordered so the x-axis doesn't plot in alphabetical order.

Comment: Thank you for your code. I learned new things from it. However, I meant to have years on the x -axis and a line you have with one colour between two years. I am sorry for my ambiguous question.

Comment: Upps . thanks was to fast. Will change!

Comment: Please See my update

Answer (score 0):

You need to tidy your data and give your columns names in order to identify them later. We can do so using `reshape2`:

```
names(df) <- c("Year", month.name)
df <- melt(df, id.var = "Year", variable.name = "Month")
```

With the data formatted like this we just need to use the correct aes in `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = value, group = Year, color = factor(Year))) +
  geom_line() + geom_point()
```